# Why is Graph API DeleteAsync throwing an error

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am using the MSGraph sdk in c# to add/remove roles from users in our active directory.  This line of code was working a few weeks ago, but last week it stopped working.  The code and the unit test that was calling it haven't changed, but it's possible the options for _graphServiceClient or out active directory settings have changed since I last saw it working. We're using Microsoft.Graph version (4.54.0), which I wouldn't be surprised it the version for that was the problem.  Does anyone know WHY the graph api call would suddenly not be supported anymore or where the documentation for the error message is?  If I can figure out why I'm getting the error I should be able to get this sorted out.

Code:

```
await _graphServiceClient.Users[GraphUserId].AppRoleAssignments[PermissionId].Request().DeleteAsync();
```

Error:

```
Code: Request_UnsupportedQuery
Message: Links to EntitlementGrant are not supported between specified entities.
```

Edit: Also, I get the same error on https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=me&method=GET&version=v1.0&GraphUrl=https://graph.microsoft.com when I try to get users/{user-id}/appRoleAssignments/{appRoleAssignment-id}

Answer (score 0):

Alright, had a conversation with our Azure admin and we got this sorted out.  Most of my roles are assigned to me through a group (IT Dev Team) that grants me permissions for all the pages in the app.  Neither our application nor I have permission to change the roles on the group, just on users.  Our solution is that we're going to have to make one or more test users for the application that we can use to test adding/removing permissions directly (no group permissions for them).

I'm going to leave this question open for a bit in case someone can link out to the documentation for the error message I received.  Being able to view the docs for the error would still qualify as an answer to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
await graphClient.ServicePrincipals[resourceId].AppRoleAssignments[item.Id].DeleteAsync();
```

or:

```
await graphClient.Users[dto.Guid.ToString()].AppRoleAssignments[item.Id].DeleteAsync();
```